# Updating state in reducer not propagating to Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update the redux state in a reducer. The updated state is not showing up in the component, even though the component is connected via a 'connect' call.

Here is the reducer code -

```
const INIT_STATE={fullData:[]}

export default createTaskReducer=(state=INIT_STATE,action)=>{
//console.log('from reducer')
switch(action.type)
{
case "createTask":fullData=state.fullData;fullData.push(action.payload);
return {...state,fullData}

case "delete":console.log("about to delete");
let allData=state.fullData.filter((value,index,arr)=>{return 
value.id!==action.payload});

state.fullData=allData;
console.log(state);
return {...state};

default: return {...state}
}

}
```

As you can see in the above reducer, in 'delete' I am trying to remove some entries from the state, updating the state the with the modified data, then creating a new state object with the same details.

Here is my combinereducers -

```
export default combineReducers({
initial:dataList,
fullData:createTaskReducer,
latestId:generateId
})
```

After the reducer is called, the following component is called by redux because the state is changed. However, I am not getting the updated value of the 'fullData' property of the state -

```
      class TaskList extends React.Component{

        constructor(props)
        {
            super(props);
        }

        renderListItem(singleItem)
        {
          //console.log(singleItem);
         return <Task title={singleItem.item.title}  desc={singleItem.item.desc} 
        dueDate= {singleItem.item.dueDate} id={singleItem.item.id}/>
        }
        componentWillMount()
        {
            if(this.props.init)
            {this.props.loadInitialData();}
        }

        render()
        {    

           if (this.props.init)
           {this.props.fullData.fullData=this.props.initial.initialData}
            console.log('printing...')

//NOT GETTING THE UPDATED STATE HERE !!
            console.log(this.props);

let renderList=this.props.init?       
        this.props.initial.initialData:this.props.fullData.fullData;


      let list=(renderList.length==0?(<View></View>):<FlatList data={renderList}  renderItem={this.renderListItem} 
        keyExtractor={val=>val.id.toString()}></FlatList>);  



            return (
        <View style={taskListStyle.containerStyle}>
       {list}
        <CustomButton title='+'  onPressHandler={()=>{Actions.createTask()}} 
        type='round' 
        styleVal={{position:'absolute',bottom:0,alignSelf:'flex-end'}}/>
           </View>
                )
            }

            }
        const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
            return state;}

        const taskListStyle=StyleSheet.create({
        containerStyle:{flex:1}})

         TaskList.defaultProps={init:false}
        export default connect(mapStateToProps,{loadInitialData})(TaskList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is barely readable. Please clean it up (indents etc.) when you ask a question.

There might be some other problems as well (is double `.fullData.fullData` intentional?), but one big issue is you're mutating the Redux state that is supposed to be immutable. E.g. this:

```
state.fullData=allData;
console.log(state);
return {...state};
```

should look like this:

```
return {...state, fullData: allData }
```

You can read more [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns).

Also you never want to modify props, so this is a no-no:

```
this.props.fullData.fullData=this.props.initial.initialData
```

You should modify data in your reducer only. I also recommend using [redux-logger](https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger) to debug how your store data is changing.

Comment: double 'fullData' is intentional. After mutating state I am copying it to a new state and returning it. So that follows redux guideline. Thanks for the 'props' tips. However, it does not explain why I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your filter comparison:

```
value.id!==action.payload
```

You are comparing an `id` with a "data".

Try this:

```
case "delete":
  const allData = [...state.fullData];
  return {
    ...state,
    fullData: allData.filter(value => value.id !== action.payload.id),
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was because the state value was being reset to initial value in the first line of the render() method.